# Avoid circular imports with generic types in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, circular-dependency

Often circular imports stemming from type checking can be avoided by skipping runtime imports based on `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`

However, it appears that generic types require evaluation at runtime, for example, the follow code does not run in 3.11.

Note that this is different from non-generic type hints, which work fine.

*mwe1.py*

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .mwe2 import A

class B:
    def get_as(self) -> list[A]:
        return []
```

*mwe2.py*

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .mwe1 import B

class A:
    def get_bs(self) -> list[B]:
        return []
```

is there a strategy for avoiding circular imports in this case?

Comment: Yes. Dammit, though I didn't need to do that anymore. Thanks

Comment: You can put abortions in weird, so they will be evaluated only for type checking, e.g `def get_as(self) -> "list[A]":`. Alternatively, consider changing your code so that it doesn't need that at all

Comment: Even if `A` and `B` were defined in the same module, you would need to quote either `list[A]` or `list[B]`, depending on which class was defined first, so this is still just a forward dependency in disguise.